# Speeding up simulation time with loops?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I created a transporterFleet with the following code in "On enter node" in Fleets properties.
When the transporter enters a specific node the speed is set by a variable called `agvCycle`.
I coded it that way because the transporters speed has to change on each node.

I noticed my simulation run time gets really slow eaven on "virtual". I think the unnecessary repetive coding might be the reason. How can I implement a loop in this case? Would that speed up the simulation time?

````
if (node == locationCycle1) {
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle1/60.0, MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle2){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle2/60.0, MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle3){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle3/60.0,MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle4){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle4/60.0, MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle5){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle5/60.0, MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle6){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle6/60.0, MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle7){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle7/60.0, MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle8){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle8/60.0, MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle9){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle9/60.0, MPS);
}
else if (node == locationCycle10){
    unit.setMaximumSpeed(agvSpeedCycle10/60.0, MPS);
}

... // Goes on till locationCycle27 and variable agvSpeedCycle27```
````

Comment: I'm not an anylogic user, but my understanding is it's based on Java. If so, the entire chain of if/else alternatives can be replaced by a `HashMap` where you use the `node` value as a key to yield the corresponding `avgSpeedCycle`. That would reduce all of the above to a single statement after the mapping is set up. Any time you see a numeric suffix to distinguish amongst a bunch of similarly named variables, you should lose the suffix and use either an array or a hash collection of some sort.

Comment: You also might want to just store those *speedCycle / 60* calculations so you're only doing them once. If you want to keep the original values, it might be worth creating a special lookup just for this, where you map each *location* to its corresponding *speed/60*. You're also passing the same `MPS` value into that function, so maybe there's some unnecessary calculation going on in there you could avoid too (since it's always the same)

Answer (score 1):

in general you want to use maps in your simulation models, in this case in particular i don't think it makes much of a difference, but for good practice you want to define a collection of type LinkedHashMap (let's call it x), the key element will be Node and the value element class will be a double

Then in the simulation start you do this:

```
x.put(locationCycle1,agvSpeedCycle1);
x.put(locationCycle2,agvSpeedCycle2);
```

etc...

Then when you want to calculate the new maximum speed you just do this:

```
unit.setMaximumSpeed(x.get(node)/60.0, MPS);
```